# Apply filter and block predicate to a new table

Tags: sql-server, database, row-level-security

I am working with a SQL Server database which has row-level security implemented. To access content for a certain user, I need to append this to the SQL query:

```
EXEC SP_SET_SESSION_CONTEXT @key=N'UserId', @value=1
```

This works fine for existing tables in the database. However I have to add a new table to the database and I'm unable to add the same security to my new table.

[This is how an existing table properties looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tl1g.png)

[This is how the new table properties looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQp0.png)

This is the code I found on the Microsoft docs and implemented it.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY RLS.NewTable
ADD FILTER PREDICATE RLS.fn_securitypredicate(AppUserId)   
    ON dbo.NewTable,  
ADD BLOCK PREDICATE RLS.fn_securitypredicate(AppUserId)   
    ON dbo.NewTable AFTER INSERT   
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

Obviously I got an error:

> Cannot find the object "RLS.fn_securitypredicate" or this object is not an inline table-valued function.

Now I don't know where to find the correct block/filter predicate to be used on the new table.

TL;DR: where in a SQL Server database are the RLS predicates listed and how do I access/view them using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Here's the microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you have the predicate function (RLS.fn_securitypredicate) in your database?

It will appear in Sql Server MS under  -> Programmability -> Functions -> Table-valued Functions:

[image]